# Spark 2.3.0 proper way to exit structured streaming process

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am learning structured streaming from the book Spark The Definitive Guide. The very first example reads from a stream of JSON files and then quit after checking a memory table 5 times with the following code fragment:

```scala
val streaming = spark.readStream.schema(dataSchema).
option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).json(/data/activity-data/")

val activityCounts = streaming.groupBy("gt").count()

val activityQuery = activityCounts.writeStream
.queryName("activity_counts")
.option("checkpointLocation","/runtime/checkpoint/spark_sstreaming/app01")
.format("memory").outputMode("complete")
.start()

 // ...
for (i <-1 to 5) { 
  spark.sql("SELECT * FROM activity_counts").collect
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}

// ... 
activityQuery.stop()
activityQuery.awaitTermination()
logger.info(s"quiting program now")
System.exit(0)
```

I submit this application to a YARN cluster of 3 nodes. The issue I am getting is these few lines appear in the stdout of the application:

```
27516 [Driver] INFO sparkAppDriverLogger  - quiting program now
27524 [task-result-getter-2] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 90.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 791, data02, executor 4): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
27527 [task-result-getter-0] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 70.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 787, data01, executor 3): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
27537 [task-result-getter-1] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 80.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 792, data03, executor 2): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
27538 [task-result-getter-3] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 81.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 793, data03, executor 2): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
27542 [task-result-getter-2] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 102.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 795, data02, executor 1): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
27543 [task-result-getter-0] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 101.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 794, data02, executor 1): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
27546 [task-result-getter-1] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 62.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 776, data01, executor 3): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
```

Somehow YARN thinks the instance has a failure and it retries the application. It doesn't matter whether I use the option "checkpointLocation" or not. The retried application will run from the beginning of the stream. This issue is repeated on each of my application submission. So I end up running the application twice for each submission. From Spark history server, I can see some stages killed and a message like this:

```
Job 5 cancelled part of cancelled job group 1ff5bc87-6c56-4e5f-abb1-2becf2bd9ac0
```

Any suggestion where I should look at?

[Updated] The solution came to me right after I submitted this question. It's the call System.exit(0) causing the issue. If I take it out and let the Scala application exit normally, the YARN application instance is marked as SUCCEEDED. This type of lines doesn't matter as well:

```
27546 [task-result-getter-1] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 62.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 776, data01, executor 3): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting this config to true? Its false by default in 2.3.0 at least.

```
spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown
```

You can set configs via SparkSession:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", true)
  .getOrCreate
```